# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' reading a CSV

Tags: python, csv, user-agent

I'm trying to learn python to implement a user agent transformation script in our analytics database.
I imported the user_agents lib to do the conversion and show me the user data. When executing this script in python reading a csv file that I extracted containing the user_agents (the csv has only one column) it returns this error:

**TypeError: nailshable type: 'list'**

Here is the script I am using:

```
import csv
from user_agents import parse

with open ('UserAgent.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader (csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print (parse (line))
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse` method takes a string as an argument. However, in your code, each `line` is a list and not a string, you can try this:

```
with open('UserAgent.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print( parse(' '.join(line)) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a hero! Saved my day